# websphere and multiple Jsession id's from Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, websphere

I am running into issues with a Internet Explorer client and a IBM websphere server application.

Internet explorer sends multiple JsessionId's to the server if you open multiple apps that have the same domain or subdomain.

For ex: if you open 'https://qa.abc123.com", Websphere responds back with a JsessionId of say "123".

Now if I open "https://abc123.com" in a different tab, Websphere responds back with a JsessionId of say "abc".

Now if I go back to 'https://qa.abc123.com" and try to login, IE sends both jesessionids to the qa websphere server.

Jsessionid: 123
Jsessionid: abc

Now how does Websphere handle these cases where it gets multiple JsessionId's for a request?

Which Jsession id will it pick up among the 2?...does it pick up the first one and then try to retrieve the session or the second one?
And what if it does not find any of the 2 jsession ids in its cache ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is write a servlet/jsp to print the jsession id. It'll probably pick the correct one for the appropriate host, because that servlet container will know something about one of the session IDs, and (most likely) not about the other.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering your question here, but I believe when you go to https://abc123.com the cookie is created for .abc123.com (all subdomains). To avoid this, try https://www.abc123.com. This should keep your two jsession ids separate (which I believe is your intent).